# How to change the local folder for an App Engine project?

Tags: apache, google-app-engine, ubuntu, gcloud, google-cloud-sdk

TIA for your help.

I recently started experimenting with Google App Engine, and I have been able to set up a project successfully.

However, I made a mistake with the location of my local files and I would like to change it.

This is the output from my console when I deploy:

***jnkrois@dev:~/Development/My_Project$ gcloud app deploy
Initializing App Engine resources...done.

You are about to deploy the following services:

 My_Project/default/1234567890 (from [/home/jnkrois/Development/My_Project/app.yaml])***

Notice that the local folder is /home/jnkrois/Development/My_Project/app.yaml

I want to change the gcloud settings in order to pull the files from my /var/www/html/My_Project/

That way I can run the project locally via my Apache server.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That way I can run the project locally via my Apache server.

In the vast majority of cases you won't be able to run your GAE project through apache. Except, *maybe*, for a totally static website with a very particular config.

The proper way to run your GAE project locally is using the development server, see [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server)

But to answer your question - there is no extra dependency of the project outside the project directory, so just move the project directory to where you want (up to you to check address any permission issues, assuming all permissions are met in the example below) and run the `gcloud` cmd from the new project location:

```
mv /home/jnkrois/Development/My_Project /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html/My_Project/
gcloud app deploy
```

Again, donno if this will help you run it through apache or not.

Comment: Thank you Dan. My doubt was the dependencies.
I changed the location of the project. Ran "gcloud app deploy" from the root of the new folder and it worked like a charm.
Also, locally my apache serves the files without a problem. 
As of right now, I have a local copy of the project running on a virtual host and a copy of the project already deployed.
In case you were wondering, it is a copy of CodeIginiter (no database yet). That is a problem for another day.